# process.node.env is undefined in eslintrc.js

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I need some linting rules to throw either an error or a warning depending on whether the build is development or production. In a React component file during development `process.env.NODE_ENV` === `'development'`.

In eslintrc.js I have:

```js
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development'; // returns true
console.log('%c process.env.NODE_ENV', 'color: green;', process.env.NODE_ENV); // returns undefined
```

I want to be able to switch between linting rule warnings. and errors like this:

```
    rules: {
        'no-tabs': 0,
        indent: [2, 'tab', { SwitchCase: 1, VariableDeclarator: 1 }],
        'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
        'no-unused-vars':
            production
                ? 'error'
                : 'warn',
```

Why is `process.env.NODE_ENV` undefined and how can I fix this?

Comment: I would imagine any environment variables would be undefined during static analysis in your IDE since the code *isn't* actually running in an environment.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's undefined during static analysis you can always do something like this:

```js
  'no-console': (() => {
      if (typeof process.env.NODE_ENV === 'undefined') {
        return 'off';
      }

      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        return 'off';
      }

      return 'error';
    })(),
```

Comment: I was struggling to set rule only to development and this works for me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You might think about just having multiple configuration files for eslint instead of trying to handle environment changes in a single file.

According to the docs:
https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#basic-configuration

You can just call eslint with the `-c` or `--config` flags and pass in the extra config file. This will merge a base config file with the file passed in the flag

An example for two lint scripts:
`eslint --config ./dev-config.js **/*.js`
`eslint --config ./prod-config.js **/*.js`